# How to create a hierarchical listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, templates, hierarchical

I was wondering how to create a Hierarchical Listview that has main nodes that read from a categories table where the sub nodes are from the subcategories table.

Its a one to many relation ship but what type of template should I give the Listview control?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged as asp-classic. Also, what do your tables look like and what have you tried so far that's not working.

Comment: Do you have only 2 levels? category and subcategory?

Comment: The tables are pretty simple, a collectables website with a main category table and a sub category table so if Art is a category then oil paintings, Watercolour and Prints could be subcategories. At the moment I am trying to figure out a layout template that would have the right hand side sit as nodes under the left. Yeah, autofil was responciple for the asp classic.